# Make Observable return only when specific Boolean case is met

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code:

```
    int finalAttempts = attempts;
    Certificate certificate = Observable.range(1, attempts)
            .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(integer -> {
                try {
                    order.update();
                    if(order.getStatus() != Status.VALID) {
                        if(integer == finalAttempts) {
                            Exceptions.propagate(new AcmeException("Order failed... Giving up."));
                        }
                    } else if(order.getStatus() == Status.VALID) {
                        Certificate cert = order.getCertificate();
                        return cert;
                    }
                } catch (AcmeException e) {
                    Exceptions.propagate(e);
                }
                return null; // return only if this is TRUE: order.getStatus() == Status.VALID
            }).toBlocking().first();
```

I'd like to know the best way to prevent this `Observable` from returning at all when the `order.getStatus() == Status.VALID` is still not true. At the same time if all try or attempt has been consumed and the status is still not true it should throw the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [filter()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) operator could be your friend in this case. Something like this comes to my mind:

```
int finalAttempts = attempts;
Certificate certificate = Observable.range(1, attempts)
        .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .filter(integer -> {
            order.update();
            return order.getStatus() == Status.VALID;
        })
        .map(integer -> {

            // do your stuff

        }).toBlocking().first();
```